# tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss, fail_on_nan_loss=False) will still raise exception with TF1.0

Tags: tensorflow

When I define a customized model_fn wtih TF1.0, I want to stop the training when loss is Nan. I tried the code below in model_fn:

```
    return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions_dict,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
        training_hooks=[tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss, fail_on_nan_loss=False)])
```

but the **fail_on_nan_loss=False** will still raise an exception, I expect it will write the warning message and stop the specific training without raising an exception.

Any suggestion on how to use tf.train.NanTensorHook correctly?

Comment: this is needed to use Hyperparams to find which combination of setting is better like suggested in [Link](http://www.michael-remington.com/machine/learning/tensorflow/neural/networks/2016/06/25/tflearn-tutorial.html).  you don't want the big loop be intrrupted due to the raised exception.

Answer (score 0):

When I explore the solution, one possible work around might helps:
I copy the NanTensorHook class from basic_session_run_hooks.py and make my own version of call inside my model_fn as below

```
        class NanTensorHook2(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
      """NaN Loss monitor by Lei.

      Monitors loss and stops training if loss is NaN.
      Can either fail with exception or just stop training.
      """

      def __init__(self, loss_tensor, fail_on_nan_loss=True):
        """Initializes NanLoss monitor.

        Args:
          loss_tensor: `Tensor`, the loss tensor.
          fail_on_nan_loss: `bool`, whether to raise exception when loss is NaN.
        """
        self._loss_tensor = loss_tensor
        self._fail_on_nan_loss = fail_on_nan_loss

      def before_run(self, run_context):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(self._loss_tensor)

      def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        if (np.isnan(run_values.results) or np.isinf(run_values.results)):
          failure_message = "Model diverged with loss = NaN or Inf."
          if self._fail_on_nan_loss:
            logging.error(failure_message)
            raise NanLossDuringTrainingError
          else:
            logging.warning(failure_message)
            # We don't raise an error but we request stop without an exception.
            run_context.request_stop()
```

then use NanTensorHook2 instead, it then started working.

Notes that I added **"np.isinf(run_values.results)"** as I believe that loss = inf should also be checked here.

any expert has better solution?