# How to fail during training on nan loss?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I try to find how to fail training after loss becomes nan

I have found the old post about how to do this for Tensorflow 1
[tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss, fail_on_nan_loss=False) will still raise exception with TF1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647403/tf-train-nantensorhookloss-fail-on-nan-loss-false-will-still-raise-exception)

But I am working currently with Tensorflow 2 and I have not found in documentation any metioning about how to do it with second version ...

Any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: There are a number of useful functions in [`tf.debugging`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging), in particular you may look at [`check_numerics`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/check_numerics) or [`enable_check_numerics`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/enable_check_numerics).

Comment: @jdehesa It is cool, but actually I cannot figure out where to put it ? Should I put it in fit function during training ? Or add as layer in model ?

Comment: You can simply do something like `loss = tf.debugging.check_numerics(loss)`. If you are using a builtin Keras loss, e.g. `loss='MSE'`, you can have a custom loss function simply as `def checked_mse(y_true, y_pred): return tf.debugging.check_numerics(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred))`. If you cannot access the point where you need to check the loss you can just resort to `tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()`, although that will add checking to everything.

Comment: Are you using tf.keras?

Comment: I am using tensorflow keras API

Comment: @jdehesa I have try to add it in my code and got the error that loss keyword argument does not exist !!

Comment: Here is code where I tried to add check_numerics     optimizer = AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.03, epsilon=0.3)
    loss = tf.debugging.check_numerics(loss='mae')
    multi_step_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)
    return multi_step_model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you can use the `TerminateOnNaN` callback:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TerminateOnNaN

term = TerminateOnNaN()

model.fit(..., callbacks=[term])
```

It does exactly what you want, you can see the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TerminateOnNaN).